# Change datatemplate control (retangle fill) from codebehind (listbox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Currently i have made a bar chart from a listbox from this example:
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/wpf-listbox-as-bar-chart.html

**What i want to do is change the color of the bars. My chart will have 5 bars and each have to be in a different color. Basically i want to change the Fill of the Rectangle.**

**EDIT:**
The ItemsControl no longer seems to be getting any content and my chart is invisible.

```
     public class GrafiekBar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int value;
    private Brush fill = Brushes.Blue;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public List<GrafiekBar> GetDataGrafiek()
    {
        int[] getallen = new int[] { 3, 5, 8, 6, 2 };
        List<GrafiekBar> list = new List<GrafiekBar>();

        for (int i = 0; i < getallen.Length; i++)
        {
            GrafiekBar bar = new GrafiekBar();
            bar.Value = getallen[i];
            bar.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            list.Add(bar);
        }

        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in  properties 
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx
    /// </summary>
    public int Value 
    {
        get { return this.value; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    } 

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return this.fill; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.fill)
            {
                this.fill = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Fill");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpLbGrafiek" ObjectType="{x:Type myClasses:GrafiekBar}" MethodName="GetDataGrafiek"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpLbGrafiekColors" ObjectType="{x:Type myClasses:GrafiekBar}" MethodName="Fill"/>


<DataTemplate x:Key="GrafiekItemTemplate">
        <Border Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle x:Name="recGrafiek" Fill="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpLbGrafiekColors}}" StrokeThickness="0"  
                    Height="45" Width="{Binding}" Margin="13.2" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="20" />
                    </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>


 <ItemsControl x:Name="icGrafiek"  
                 Margin="0" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpLbGrafiek}}"
                 ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GrafiekItemTemplate}" 
                 Grid.RowSpan="5" 
                 Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                 >
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Best regards.

Comment: You should return a `List<GrafiekBar>`, *do not* create UIElements in code behind, the `ListBox` will create the `ListBoxItems` for you, also if you return `ListBoxItems` the `ItemTemplate` *will be ignored*, you should see [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) regarding that.

Comment: My list does not seem to be updating with the values now though? Made a second edit listing the method that fills up the itemsControl. But the XAML parse error is indeed gone now though, although my chart remains empty now. Regards Rakr

Comment: Did you set a default value for `Fill`? If you didn't you will not see anything as the `Fill` of the `Rectangles` will be `null`.

Comment: Added a default value but i no longer get any data displayed anymore. I updated the entire post with only relevant code now. Been looking at the databinding for some time now and cannot see whats wrong. Is it because i am using a ItemsControl? Tried a listbox and it had a scrollbar but everything was univisible.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [data templating overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and trying to do something simple in a clean environment until to have a good grasp of it (also read the article about debugging bindings if you haven't already and always be on the watch for binding errors). Can't really tell what is wrong there.

Comment: Okay thanks for your time! The error must be somewhere in GetDataGrafiek() cause if i try returning a normal int array it does fill up. Maybe i need to do something to actually populate the ItemsControl due to using a list<GrafiekBar> ?

Comment: Didn't you change the bindings as shown in my answer? If you just return an int list the `{Binding Value}` should fail as there is no `Value` property anymore.

Comment: Okay i finally have it solved, thanks a BUNCH H.B! I did indeed mess up the binding a bit, made the chart part in a new solution and solved it. Will indeed read up on those useful links you posted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always avoid direct interaction with the controls used for templating, instead [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) everything you need to change to your item, then edit the property in question on the item.

Instead of using just the values you will need a collection of more complex objects, at the very least they need two properties:

```
public class Bar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double Value { get; set; } // Implement interface in those properties for binding
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

([Implementing `INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx))

```
<!-- in the template -->
<Rectangle Width="{Binding Value}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" .../>
```

```
var bar = (Bar)lbGrafiek.Items.CurrentItem;
bar.Fill = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit further what you exactly mean with some code? Cause it seems i am trying to solve this problem the complete wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks H.B. I will take a look at this new approach.

Comment: Getting a xaml parse error when trying to cast the current item to the class that implements the Inotify interface (made it inherit from listbox though).{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'WpfApplication.Classes.Bar'."}

Comment: @Rakr: As i said, your collection needs to be of that type, you cannot keep on using the old int collection.

Comment: Even when i change my collections H.B. i keep getting this error I'm afraid.

Comment: @Rakr: That should not be the case, if you use a collection of `Bars` the current item *has to be* a `Bar` as well.

Comment: @Rakr post your edited code in your question so we can see the new code. Maybe then we can show you whats going wrong